# interrogate the Data in Lync 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, lync-2010

I developed a seat plan website - it uses the Lync SDK to pull back user details - (i.e. when a name is clicked on the map it passes the name into the Search box and then lists the person in the results list and then you can start an instant conversation, etc).

I want to possibly expand upon this now and I was wondereing does anyone know if its possible/have any URLS, source code that would allow me to pull back the status of all the people in the office from there Lync status (i.e. available/busy,etc).

Also the other information stored about the person withing Lync - the Office/Mobile/Calendar details - is it possible to pull this off to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see "real" presence of a user, and recieve realtime updates to that presence, then you need to add the user as contacts in Lync. I'm guessing in your scenario that's not ideal (or even possible) so you'll need to search for contacts, and then query for their presence.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378560.aspx) should get you started with searching for a contact

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Lync 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18898)?  I would think that's the place to start...

Comment: Yeah - I already use the Lync SDK as part of my site - a search box is populated with a persons name from the map and it brings back their details - what I was hoping for was a URL or if someone had an example of actually pulling out the data that is contained in the LYNC UI.